# Reload a UICollectionView from a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UICollectionView` and within this I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` which has a button with an action attached to it. The action deletes the object from core data.

I am then wanting to perform a `[self reloadData]`. But how would I call this method from within the `UICollectionViewCell` Class?

Comment: you need protocol or notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can call it in your IBAction inside of your `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notification_name" object:nil];
```

Inside of the class you want to reload, you can put this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reloadDataNow)
                                             name:@"notification_name"
                                           object:nil];
```

Inside of the same class you want to reload create this new method `reloadDataNow`

```
- (void)reloadDataNow {
    [self.yourCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create delete or notification in `UIViewController` and in  `cellforItemAtindexPath` set that delegate to `UIViewController`. 
In button action inside `UICollectionViewCell` performing operation (deletes the object) and call `delegate`

when receiving delegate callback in `UIViewController` perform `[collectionView reload];`

Answer (score 0):

This is a Swift 4+ version of J. Lopes's answer:

Place this inside the `IBAction` of your `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "notification_name"), object: nil)
```

Place this inside the `viewDidLoad()` of the receiving class:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reloadDataNow), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "notification_name"), object: nil)
```

And this is the function you want to trigger in the receiving class once `IBAction` is pressed from the `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
@objc func reloadDataNow(_ notification: Notification) {
    self.yourCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```